# Function works only in Safari, other browsers throw `Uncaught TypeError: X is not a function`. Where's the problem?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, scope, javascript-function-declaration

I implemented a new feature to our CRM and everything works as it should on Safari (macOS), but it throws `Uncaught TypeError: X is not a function` on every other browser we tested it on (Chrome, Firefox, Edge). This is the piece of code that is the culprit:

```js
if (window.changeLabel === 'undefined') {
  function changeLabel() {
    // Do something
  }
  changeLabel();
} else {
  changeLabel();
}
```

Why is it working only on Safari? Why is `changeLabel` not a function even after I check for its existence? Is this not the way to check if a function exists or not?

Comment: Because you are not defining the function `changeLabel` in the `else` part. Just the way you have defined in the `if`  part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.changeLabel === 'undefined'` will return `false` regardless of browser because you are comparing a property value with the string `'undefined'` and not the value `undefined`.

In Safari's sloppy mode the following will "leak" the function declaration outside of the block within which is was declared.

```js
if(false) { function foo() {} }
console.log(foo) // function foo() {} in Safari, undefined in Chrome-based browsers
```

Chrome's sloppy mode behaves differently due to a different interpretation of the spec (the Web Compatibility Annex IIRC), meaning the function does not "leak", and remains undeclared.

[More details at the end ]

And so in Safari your code accidentally works by leaking the function declaration, making it visible outside the block.

Two things to do:

1. Use strict mode in all production-facing code
2. Use `typeof` for its intended purpose of checking for undeclared identifiers

```
if (typeof changeLabel !== 'function') {
  window.changeLabel = function() {
    // Do something.
  }
}
// Now you can always use changeLabel...
```

**More details**

The reason for all this faffing is that the scope of function declarations inside blocks was never really properly specified in early versions of JavaScript (it was exclusively a function-scoped language back then), and so browser vendors did their own different things. When TC-39 finally decided to standardise this behavior in ES2015, the "Don't Break The Web" requirement meant that the sloppy mode specification for this edge case ended-up being insanely complicated and counterintuitive, leading to two different implementations (only one of which is correct).

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you would usually register a polyfill. Normally, you'd do it like this:

```js
if (window.changeLabel === 'undefined') {
  window.changeLabel = function() {
    // Do something
  }
}

changeLabel();
```

Note how we don't need the `else` block there.

Answer (score 0):

You can probe for the existence of `window.changeLabel` and assign it if is does not exist in one line, like:

```js
window.changeLabel = window.changeLabel || 
  function() { console.log(`changeLabel here`); }
changeLabel();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
if (window.changeLabel === 'undefined') {
  function changeLabel() {
    // Do something
  }
  changeLabel();
} else {
  function changeLabel();{
    // Do something
  }
}
```